# How can I display time and date in notification?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-push-notification

How can I send a notification for user with the time and date? After user have done the appointment, it will send a notification for user to let user know the date and time. Anyone can help me

This is my data of date and time store in firebase
[image]

private TextView mDate;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_user_information);
    mDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvdate);

    //declare the database reference object. This is what we use to access the database.
    //NOTE: Unless you are signed in, this will not be useable.
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();
    buttonBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
    final FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    userID = user.getUid();


    buttonBack.setOnClickListener(this);


    // Read from the database
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            mDate.setText(dataSnapshot.child(userID).child("Appointment").child("date").getValue(String.class));

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: can display using textview and string

Comment: how to use textview? i have upload my code but this code got error i have try many ways to do but still can't get it.

Comment: Hi Bleach, start a basic Android free course on Udacity to learn to use it

Comment: I have done the notification part but just can't display my data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read [Firebase Cloud Messaging for Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/)

If you want to manage data before, [Read cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) too.